# Module Not Found Error for Directory after importing python model in Rasa Chatbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa, rasa-nlu

So I tried a majority of the solutions on this platform and none of it worked. Im desperately in need of help.

I'm using Rasa Chatbot in my project and im trying to use actions. In actions im trying to call a getAllProducts function from the negotiate.py python file in my backend directory. My project file structure looks like this.

[image]

and I import the function like this in actions.py

[image]

Ill be calling the function as follows

[image]

but im getting the following error when I try to execute this in rasa,
[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You need to have the directory that contains "backup" be on your Python path.  Something like `sys.path.append( os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../..')`, although there are other ways to accomplish that.

Comment: can you give me an example please @TimRoberts

Comment: Um, that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can go back in an import only inside a module with the `__init__` file. If you want to do import negotiate as nego you must put the file negotiate.py inside the action directory of rasa chatbot.
If you don't want to do it, you must use

```
import os
import sys; sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../..'))
```